# can't get any of the responses for scrolling textviews when keyboard presents from stack overflow to work

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I don't know why my attempts to get the scrollview to move the textviews up so they remain visible when the keyboard presents via stack overflow responses haven't been working, but they haven't for me. Translating the apple documentation below into Swift should be enough for me to get this to work, but I don't know Objective C well enough to do this. Would someone be willing to translate the following into Swift 3?

```
1.// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
            name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
         name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

2. // Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
 - (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

// If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
// Your app might not need or want this behavior.
CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}

3.// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
    - (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
     {
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. I have used this code with UIView, though. You should be able to make those adjustments for scrollview.

```
    func addKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            let duration = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
// if using constraints            
// bottomViewBottomSpaceConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height
self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

        let duration = notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
//if using constraint
//        bottomViewBottomSpaceConstraint.constant = 0
self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to remove notifications at right place.

```
func removeKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```